# How to retrieve the previous row of a table in a database?

Tags: java, mysql

I created an interface called 'Customer Navigation Form'. In this form when I click the "Back" button I want to the load the details of the previous customer.And if the data  of the first customer are on the form,when I click the "Back" button a message dialog should show the message "This is the first customer".But my program doesn't perform this task.

Here is the code I wrote..

```
  backBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                    String id=idText.getText();
                    String SQL="Select from customer where id='"+id+"'";

                    try{
                        Class.forName("com.mysql,jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Thogakade","root","1234");
                        Statement stm=conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rst=stm.executeQuery(SQL);
                        if(rst.previous()){
                            idText.setText(rst.getString("id"));
                            nameText.setText(rst.getString("name"));
                            addressText.setText(rst.getString("address"));
                            salaryText.setText(rst.getString("salary"));
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CustomerNavigationForm.this,"This is the first customer..");
                        }
                    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CustomerNavigationForm.this,ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to catch an exception and ignore it.

Comment: no it's not that i ignored the exception.I just wanted to see whether this code block runs correctly or not.

Comment: You ignored the exception. It means you ignored the reason why your code doesn't run.

Comment: When you're ignoring exceptions, you're not supposed to ask a question on SO. You're supposed to handle the exception, look at the stacktrace to see what the problem is, then you're supposed to try to handle the problem, and only after you've done everything you can, you should ask about it on SO.

Comment: `rst.previous()` immediately after executing the query will always be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

First question to ask is how are these sorted? By ID?

In that case change the SQL query to where id < ? order by id desc limit 1

This will get you the previous record.